# How to get the Alarm ID from Alarm Manager

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-alarms

I am creating a Remainder Application, It starts alarm on the specified time and repeats until user stops it.

I generate a unique number and pass it to my AlarmManager class,

```
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                this.getApplicationContext(), remainderID.intValue(), intent, 0);

// remainderID is unqiue value, generated from Database.
```

I know the steps of cancel the Alarm, but i am unable to understand how to get this ID in Broadcast Receiver Class.

Kindly guide me.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass this ID using `putExtra()` to the intent as follows

```
intent.putExtra("ID", remainderID.intValue();
```

And then pass this intent to the pending intent as you did.

In the Broadcast Receiver Class you can retrieve it as follow:

```
intent.getIntExtra("ID", -1);
// Make sure the name is exactly the same in put and get
// Put the default value as an int you're sure doesn't exist in your database
```

I hope this will help!

Answer (score 0):

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
            this.getApplicationContext(), remainderID.intValue(), intent, 0);
```

Add your unique code and whatever other data you require to the intent above, and extract the same intent in AlarmService class below.

```
public class AlarmService extends IntentService {

    @Override
    public void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

        if (intent == null) return;

        try
        {
//          send the intent to your AlarmManager class and process it there.

            YourAlarmManager.processAlarm(intent, this);            
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps! :)